# How to check wheter the Azure AD token send by React to Node.js is valid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

Hi I have a code from `https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa`
I changed it a little bit, so instead calling an `Microsoft Graph API` endpoint, I call mine endpoint on `localhost:7000`.
So it basically starts with me logging in (here i did not change enything). Then there is this function which acquires token:

```
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [graphData, setData] = useState(null);

  function RequestProfileData() {
    // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
    instance
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: accounts[0],
      })
      .then((response) => {
        callMyEndpoint(response.accessToken).then((response) =>
          setData(response)
        );
      });
  }
```

it uses function `callMyEndpoint` which looks like this:

```
export async function callMyEndpoint(accessToken) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

  headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
  };

  return fetch("http://localhost:7000/myendpoint", options)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.log(error)) // if the user is not logged in- catch an error;
}
```

Now, onto my `Node.js` backend application where the `http://localhost:7000/myendpoint` is served.

```
app.post("/myendpoint", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("TOKEN", req.headers.authorization); // it is being printed here, everything seems fine.

  // here i would like to check whether the token is valid
  // if req.headers.authorization == AZURE_TOKEN?
  // How to do this?
});
```

And now the question is? How to check in backend if the token send from frontend is valid for the user, so only logged users, or users which are added in my `app registration` in azure can post onto this request?

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the libraries such as [validate-azure-ad-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-azure-ad-token)  or you can write your own logic using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)
- Here I have my custom logic for that first you will need client_id , tenat_id and scope name.
- I am assuming you already have client and tenant id and for scope name it will be available in the `Expose Api` tab of your app registration.

[image]

Here I have console app which will take your token and try to validate it.

```
var  jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var token = 'your Token';
  

var  clientid = '' ;
var  tenantid = "" ;
var  scope = "";

// Create an audiance variable 
var  audiance = 'api://'+clientid;



// decoded token
var  decodedToken = jwt.decode(token , {complete :true});

if((decodedToken.payload.aud==audi)&&(decodedToken.payload.scp==scope)&&(decodedToken.payload.tid==tenantid))
{
    console.log("The token is valid");
}
else
{
    console.log("The Token is invalid")
}
```

Output :

[image]